# Receiving Data about bot user, Profile pic, Profile count

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I started to code a bot that gives me simple info from telegram users like username, id, and profile photo, and how many profiles they got.
according to [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.userprofilephotos.html) package (telegram.ext) i wrote this code and the error is " caused error "'total_count'"

```
def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Hello There!')
    user = update.message.from_user
    print('You talk with user {} and his user ID: {} '.format(user['username'], user['id']))
    userprofilephotos = update.message.from_user
    print('The user total profile {}'.format(userprofilephotos['total_count']))
```

and I imported these things

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the `get_profile_photos` method (documentation [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.user.html#telegram.User.get_profile_photos))

```py
userprofilephotos = update.message.from_user.get_profile_photos()
```

Now it should work as expected